# How to block typescript 2.0 from walking up all parent directories while resolving modules?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Upgraded to Typescript 2.0 (2.1.6) and it started giving "Duplicate identifier" errors. After taking a closer look it turned out that Typescript started importing @types from all upper directories (essentially other projects).

What should be the configuration to let Typescript to ignore upper node_modules?

```
src
 └── node_modules << *** how to ignore it? ***
     └── @types

 └── my.app << *** how to build this folder and down only? ***
         └── node_modules
             └── @types
```

**EDIT**: Here is an example of error I'm getting:

typings/globals/mocha/index.d.ts(30,13): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'describe'.
../../../node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts(9,18): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'describe'.

listFiles: true shows @types/jasmine being imported from upper folder:

```
C:/src/<project>/<folder>/<my.app>/typings/globals/mocha/index.d.ts
C:/src/node_modules/@types/jasmine/index.d.ts
```

If I rename upper node_modules folder then build succeeds.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types) specifies that node_modules in current directory and all parents will be traversed unless you specify `typeRoots`.

So in theory, the answer should be this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

Since you still want to include the types from the current directory.

*Unfortunately* this doesn't seem to work correctly for me.

Answer (score 4):

In this helps anyone, setting `"types": []` in my tsconfig.json worked for me. See this github comment.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13992#issuecomment-279020210

Answer (score 2):

You need both `baseUrl` and `typeRoots` for it to actually work.

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, and inferred the same thing as @peterjwest from the docs - however after reading this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27026, I think I misunderstood the intent of `typeRoots` (which appears to be useful only when configuring global types rather than module types).

In my case, the solution was to configure `baseUrl` and `paths` for the conflicting type (which in my case was react):

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "react": ["node_modules/@types/react"]
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

This seems to work for telling typescript that I want to specifically resolve that type from my local `node_modules`.

Comment: I needed both fixes. The accepted answer for the global types and yours for `"webpack": ["node_modules/@types/webpack"]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a root directory in the compiler options. [See the official documentation.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types)

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       "typeRoots" : ["./typings"]
   }
}
```

Comment: With this setting typescript complains with this error: error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'globals'.

Comment: Hm, you can either try adding `lib` property to your `compilerOptions` or instead use `exclude`.