# TypeScript: nested npm package causes errors (Duplicate identifier)

Tags: typescript, npm

I have a project folder with a `node_modules` at the root level and another one inside a subfolder called `functions`. Like this,

```
├── functions
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── index.js.map
│   ├── index.ts
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── node_modules
│   └── tsconfig.json
├── package.json
└── node_modules
```

I want to compile the typescript files inside this `functions` folder, but it keeps looking into the root node_modules and gives me errors,

```
tsc --project functions
functions/node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(60,13): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'global'.
functions/node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(84,13): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'require'.
node_modules/@types/react-native/index.d.ts(8365,11): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'global'.
node_modules/@types/react-native/index.d.ts(8366,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'require'.
```

How can I tell typescript to forget about the upper level `node_modules` or fix this in another way?

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "outDir": ".",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "./**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

Comment: Maybe: `cd functions && tsc`. What is the content of `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: cd didn't make a difference. added tsconfig

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

this solution work for me
I found the answer here
[How to block typescript 2.0 from walking up all parent directories while resolving modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42150920/how-to-block-typescript-2-0-from-walking-up-all-parent-directories-while-resolvi)